# mailx issue - email address starting with #

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have a requirement to generate report and send them to a distribution list. 
The problem I am facing is when sending out the email using mailx. The email address (DL) we have is starting with # and because of this it's not recognizing the email and throwing the below error.

Error:

> Send options without primary recipient specified

When I try to put the email under "" then no email has been send out.

I did a echo and could see `$RECIPIENT` has the full email address as the value.

```
RECIPIENT=$RECIPIENT"#AppMIReporting@domain.com";

echo "$BODY" | mailx -r "$SENDER" -s "$SUBJECT" -a "$ODFILENAME" -a "$LOFILENAME" "$RECIPIENT"
```

OS is Linux.

How can I solve it?

Comment: `$RECIPIENT` would start with a `#` if it is unset or empty when entering this code fragment.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? when I did the echo to check teh values in $RECIPIENT it has the whole email address "#AppMIReporting@domain.com" as expected.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the question was about _why_ the mail address started with a `#`. If that is indeed the correct address, then why do you _append_ it to the `RECIPIENT` variable? Does that variable contain anything since previously? It should not contain backslashes or newlines.

Comment: ok, may not be the correct way. I am setting up the value for RECIPIENT variable. The problem is mailx command  is NOT working with this email address, when I test it with any other address that does not start with hash it works fine. Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: Have you tried putting the address in quotes?  Note that this requires escaping (`$RECIPIENT\"#AppMIReporting@domain.com\"`) or the use of nested quotes (`$RECIPIENT'"#AppMIReporting@domain.com"'`).

Answer (score 1):

Use `\#mail@mail.com`; this would solve the issue.

Comment: How would it solve the issue? Also, what issue would it solve?

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly, your first character `#` is making you problems here.
So I would suggest you to use `cut` command to remove the fist character

`CLEAN_EMAIL=$(echo $RECIPIENT | cut -c 2-); echo $CLEAN_EMAIL`

Comment: As far as I understand, the address, including the initial `#`, is the correct address.

Comment: Yes, thats correct. The correct email address is including the #. i.e. #AppMIReporting@domain.com. I have to use this as it is when sending the email.

Comment: so you need to eliminate `#` sign in order to work with `mailx` , as you mention in the comment above right? 
`when I test it with any other address that does not start with hash it works fine`

Comment: No, I do not want to eliminate hash # symbol. If I did it will be an invalid email address. The correct email address is #AppMIReporting@domain.com. i.e. with ahsh symbol. I think since the email having # I am getting issues when sending out the email. I would like to know how to handle this issue and use this email in mailx to send out the emails.

Comment: That is strange, when I execute this 
`echo "BODY" | mailx -r "SENDER" -s "SUBJECT" -a "/tmp/traffic_ifeth0" "#mail@mail.com"` 
I get no error.
Without hash, I am able to receive email and attachment.